# What type of tape do I use on a dryer vent?

Tags: dryer, ducts

I need to install a dryer periscope vent in my new dryer unit, However, it needs to be sealed for leaks. What type of tape should be used to tape a periscope dryer vent?

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate: [How do I connect a dryer to a dryer vent?](http://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/4529/how-do-i-connect-a-dryer-to-a-dryer-vent)

Answer (score 16):

First, what you do *not* want to use is duct tape, the adhesive fails under the extreme temperatures.

For dryer vents and HVAC ducts, you should seal seams with a foil backed tape. This is designed to be airtight and handle the temperature swings that would cause other types of tape to fail.

[image: foil tape]

<sub>Note: sample product image, no affiliation or recommendation for this specific brand.</sub>

Comment: Duct tape is great for just about everything EXCEPT ducts

Comment: There are foil-backed tape roll products which are labelled as « multi-purpose / hvac » and some that are specifically marked for dryer vent installation. gimmick?

Answer (score 6):

Dryer vents should be sealed with foil tape as they can withstand the high temperatures encountered during machine use.  Other tapes, even duct tape, are susceptible to failure under the extreme heat.  Non-foil tape can also catch on fire.